# subobjects of class module not working in vba for excel

Tags: class, vba, collections, excel

I've searched for a bit, but I couldn't find a similar enough question/answer.  So here it goes:

I have a class object called Project.  A Project can have multiple Scenarios assoicated with it.

I've created the class modules for each object.  But I am having difficulty in, I believe, instantiating the Scenarios collection for a given Project.

Here are the class modules:

**1) cProject:**

```
Private pProjectID As Integer 
Private pName As String 
Private pDateCreated As String 
Private pScenarios As cScenarios

' PROPERTIES

Public Property Get ProjectID() As Integer
    ProjectID = pProjectID 
End Property
Public Property Let ProjectID(value As Integer)
    pProjectID = value 
End Property
Public Property Get name() As String
    name = pName 
End Property 
Public Property Let name(value As String)
    pName = value 
End Property 
Public Property Get Scenarios() As cScenarios
    Set Scenarios = pScenarios 
End Property
Public Property Set Scenarios(value As cScenarios)
    Set pScenarios = value 
End Property
```

**2) cScenarios collection class module:**

```
Private pScenarios As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pScenarios = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pScenarios = Nothing
End Sub
Public Function Item(index As Variant) As cScenario
    Set Item = pScenarios.Item(index)
End Function
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = pScenarios.Count
End Property
Public Sub Add(obj As cScenario)
    pScenarios.Add obj
End Sub
Public Sub Remove(index As Variant)
    pScenarios.Remove index
End Sub
```

**And finally (3) the Scenario class object:**

```
Private pScenarioID As Integer
Private pName As String
Private pDateCreated As String
Private pParent As cProject

Public Property Get ScenarioID() As Integer
    ScenarioID = pScenarioID
End Property
Public Property Let ScenarioID(value As Integer)
    pScenarioID = value
End Property
Public Property Get name() As String
    name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let name(value As String)
    pName = value
End Property
Public Property Get parent() As cProject
    parent = pParent
End Property
Public Property Let parent(value As cProject)
    pParent = value
End Property
```

Here is a standard module:

```
Sub test1()

Dim cS As cScenarios
Dim s As cScenario

Set cS = New cScenarios

For i = 1 To 3
    Set s = New cScenario
    s.name = "s" & i
    cS.Add s
Next

Debug.Print cS.Item(3).name
Debug.Print cS.Count

End Sub
```

This works. All is good. For now.  I am able to populate cS with multiple scenarios.  However, if I reference the scenarios collection as a child object of the project (see below in test2() ), I get a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" triggered on the cs.Add call.

```
Sub test2()

Dim p As cProject
Dim cS As cScenarios
Dim s As cScenario

Set p = New cProject
Set cS = p.Scenarios

For i = 1 To 3
    Set s = New cScenario
    s.name = "s" & i
    cS.Add s
Next

Debug.Print cS.Item(3).name
Debug.Print cS.Count

End Sub
```

What did I do wrong building my class modules and/or how do I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Your `parent` properties in the scenario class should be using `Set` for assigning and returning values (and the `Property Let parent` should be `Property Set parent`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `pScenarios` in the `cProject` class before trying to access it with `Add()`.
You can fix that by adding an initializer to `cProject`:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pScenarios = New cScenarios
End Sub
```

This will guarantee that the `cS` instance will not be `Nothing` when you try to invoke `Add` on it inside `test2`.
Another way (weaker IMO) would be to set `p.Scenarios = new cScenarios` after newing up `p` inside `test2`.
Also, make sure that the property setter for `cScenario.parent` is `Property Set` instead of `Property Let`.